# Unable to make ReportLab correctly print unicode fonts

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab, unicode-string

I am trying to print Korean characters using the hygothic-medium font. I have font as 'korean.h2gtrm.ttf'file under the site-packages\reportlab\fonts folder.
 I did the following :-

```
 pdfmetrics.registerFont(UnicodeCIDFont(TTFont('HYGothic- 
 Medium','korean.h2gtrm.ttf')))
 pdfmetrics.registerFontFamily('HYGothic-Medium',normal='HYGothic- 
 Medium',bold='HYGothic-Medium',italic='HYGothic- 
 Medium',boldItalic='HYGothic- 
 Medium')
 addMapping('HYGothic-Medium',0, 0, 'korean.h2gtrm') #normal
 addMapping('HYGothic-Medium', 0, 1, 'korean.h2gtrm')
 addMapping('HYGothic-Medium',1, 0, 'korean.h2gtrm')
 addMapping('HYGothic-Medium',1, 1, 'korean.h2gtrm')
 pstyle= ParagraphStyle(name='KOR', fontName = 'HYGothic-Medium', 
  fontSize = 10 ))
  p=Paragraph(text,pstyle)) # where text is my Korean characters
  story.append(p) # error !!
```

I get the following error:-

```
   Can't map determine family/bold/italic for hygothic-medium
   paragraph text '<para>\uc724\uadfc Machine</para>' caused exception
```

Any suggestions ?.